# How to add new array into specific object of another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've tried to find an answer but was not successful.

The sample of json data, lets say it would be named **mainArray**:

```
[{
  "id": 4455,
  "key1": 44,
  "key2": 55
},
{
  "id": 1122,
  "key1": 11,
  "key2": 22
}]
```

The sample of data **nestedArray** needs to be added in **mainArray**:

```
[{
  "nestedkey0": 'Value0',
  "nestedkey1": "Value1",
  "nestedkey2": "Value2"
},
{
  "nestedkey0": "Value3",
  "nestedkey1": "Value4",
  "nestedkey2": "Value5"
}]
```

And we have to check if "id" key (in **mainArray**) equals "specificId" variable:

```
 var specificId = 4455;
```

In case they are equal — we need to add **nestedArray** into the object of **mainArray** as a new key with list of objects, so returned result should be like this:

```
[{
  "id": 4455,
  "newKey": [{
      "nestedkey0": 'Value0',
      "nestedkey1": "Value1",
      "nestedkey2": "Value2"
    },
    {
      "nestedkey0": "Value3",
      "nestedkey1": "Value4",
      "nestedkey2": "Value5"
    }];
  "key1": 44,
  "key2": 55
},
{
  "id": 1122,
  "key1": 11,
  "key2": 22
}];
```

Here's a sample of code on Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YJ3lTbleKrBJBaJm7VwU?p=preview

I've got a feeling that shouldn't be hard, but I'm not quite experienced in angularjs to resolve this task.
Thank you in advance for your answers!

**Update**

Updated code in Plunker with answer of **Nina Scholz** (link is above)

And another solution from **Halcyon**

http://jsbin.com/xaxagusuma/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I'm new in angularjs and plane javascript, so I've tried to find solution here, but I couldn't. I've also tried push() method, but it adds **nestedArray** like sibling of objects in **mainArray**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for iterating, because of a possible short-circuiting.

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var mainArray = [{ "id": 4455, "key1": 44, "key2": 55 }, { "id": 1122, "key1": 11, "key2": 22 }],
    nastedArray = [{ "nastedkey0": 'Value0', "nastedkey1": "Value1", "nastedkey2": "Value2" }, { "nastedkey0": "Value3", "nastedkey1": "Value4", "nastedkey2": "Value5" }],
    specificId = 4455;

mainArray.some(function (a) {
    if (a.id === specificId) {
        a.newKey = nastedArray;
        return true;
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mainArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect this isn't very hard. The hardest part is finding the correct object to insert the *nastedArray*.

```
var mainArray = [/**/];
var nastedArray = [/***/];
var index = null;
var specificId = 4455;
for (var i = 0; index === null, i < mainArray.length; i += 1) {
    if (mainArray[i].id === specificId) {
        index = i;
    }
}
if (index !== null) {
    mainArray[index].newKey = nastedArray;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use your answer here http://jsbin.com/xaxagusuma/edit?html,js,console,output, but it looks like there is a syntax errors. But i guess your solution should be correct too.

Comment: if (index !== null) {
    mainArray[index].newKey = nastedArray;
  } In your code - new key getting value of specificId var. When I replaced specificId to var nastedArray — it created required array.

Comment: I'd love to vote up your solution, but It's my first question here, so I got low rep =) But, tnx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

*The find() method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.*

(have a look at the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility)!)

```js
var mainArray = [{ "id": 4455, "key1": 44, "key2": 55 }, { "id": 1122, "key1": 11, "key2": 22 }],
    nastedArray = [{ "nastedkey0": 'Value0', "nastedkey1": "Value1", "nastedkey2": "Value2" }, { "nastedkey0": "Value3", "nastedkey1": "Value4", "nastedkey2": "Value5" }],
    specificId = 4455;


var item = mainArray.find(x => x.id === specificId);
if (item !== undefined) {
  item.newKey = nastedArray;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(mainArray));
```

Comment: As you suggested I've look at the compatibility table and it looks like this method isn't supports by IE. Unfortunately it does not suit me. But anyway — thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, it has limited support but that could be bypassed with the polyfil mentioned on the page. Nevertheless, it's just another alternative :)

Comment: Different ways to solve one problem — It's a perfect way to study new tool/lang/etc... Tnx for your solution, appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about keeping it simple :)

```
    for (var i = 0, i < mainArray.length; i++) {
        if (mainArray[i].id === specificId) {
            mainArray[i].newKey = nestedArray;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Will work in all browsers.

Comment: Omg, It looks really nice and simple ))